# php не отрабатывает в составе sh файла

Tags: php, sh

Вызов php в sh файле не срабатывает. эти строчки просто пропускаются. В консоли все работает. А в составе sh не выполняется. Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли выполнить такие инструкции *(инструкции не точные, приведены для примера)*

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/www/www-root/data/www/
sh backup.sh
/etc/init.d/apache2 stop
php -f export.php 1
php -f export.php 2
php -f export.php 3
```

Comment: Для файла export.php выставлены права на исполнение этого файла? `chmod +x export.php`

Comment: да права: rwxr-xr-x (0755)

Comment: А вывод `bash -x script.sh` сможете приложить?

Comment: вернул: + php -f /var/www/www-root/data/www/путь/test.php

Comment: @AlexZloj значит shell скрипт не пропускает строку запуска, вероятнее всего что-то с содержимым `export.php`, возможно в нем стоит указать абсолютные пути.

Comment: пошел от обратного. наоборот в php файле запускаю shell - так работает нормально. пути все абсолютные. странно как то. задача выполнена, но вот разобраться бы почему не хочет...